# JUnit5 @Test is not Recognized as a Test

Tags: maven, testing, junit

IDE: Intellij IDEA

```
package ...;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class ApplicationStartupTest {

    @Test
    void Foo() {
        assertEquals(1,2);
    }

}
```

This @Test is not recognized as a test. I get as an output "no test were found".
However, when I use @Property tests, they are recognized as tests and run successfully.

How to make @Test recognized as a test to run with "mvn test"?

Comment: Please show your pom file and log outp

Comment: I could fix it by changing one of my imports.

Answer (score 2):

`import org.junit.Test;` was wrong, fixed by changing it to:

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

Comment: Because that is a junit4 test